# resize ec2 instance from t2 to m5

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am trying to resize my t2.medium ec2 instance to m5.large

i followed the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

but i couldn't  install the NVMe drivers on my instance

```
sudo nvme id-ctrl -v /dev/nvme1n1
```

output

`/dev/nvme1n1: No such file or directory`

and

```
lsblk
```

`NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /`

Comment: did you run the commands above on the t2 or m5 instance?

Comment: t2 instance @LucaGibelli

Comment: take a snapshot and start it as m5?

Comment: i thought about AMI but the AMI should be prepared don't you think snapshots also should be prepared ?

Comment: the instance looks ready to me. Can you give it a spin?

Comment: i think the ebs will still be xvda instead of nvme

Comment: I don't think so. The doc only says you must **install** the nvme driver. The conversion will be done by aws itself.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: No actualy but i solved by using the uuid instead in this command sudo nvme id-ctrl -v UUID then i just changed my instance type and worked